# Resolving an ES6 module imported from a URL with Rollup

Tags: es6-modules, rollupjs

It is perfectly valid to import from a URL inside an ES6 module and as such I've been using this technique to reuse modules between microservices that sit on different hosts/ports:

```
import { authInstance } from "http://auth-microservice/js/authInstance.js"
```

I'm approaching a release cycle and have started down my usual path of bundling to IIFEs using rollup. Rollup doesn't appear to support es6 module imports from URLs, I think it should as this is allowed in the spec :(

> **module-name**
>   The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quotes and double quotes Strings are allowed. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

I've dug through the interwebs for an hour now and have come up with nothing. Has anybody seen a resolver similar to rollup-plugin-node-resolve for resolving modules from URLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to move on from this quickly so ended up just writing a skeleton of a rollup plugin. I still feel that resolving absolute paths should be a core feature of rollup.

**Updated snippet**

We have been using this to transpile production code for several of our apps for a considerable amount of time now.

```js
const fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    axios = require("axios")

const createDir = path => !fs.existsSync(path) && fs.mkdirSync(path)
const mirrorDirectoryPaths = async ({ cacheLocation, url }) => {
    createDir(cacheLocation)
    const dirs = [], scriptPath = url.replace(/:\/\/|:/g, "-")

    let currentDir = path.dirname(scriptPath)
    while (currentDir !== '.') {
        dirs.unshift(currentDir)
        currentDir = path.dirname(currentDir)
    }
    dirs.forEach(d => createDir(`${cacheLocation}${d}`))
    return `${cacheLocation}${scriptPath}`
}

const cacheIndex = {}
const writeToDiskCache = async ({ cacheLocation, url }) => {
    //Write a file to the local disk cache for rollup to pick up.
    //If the file is already existing use it instead of writing a new one.
    const cached = cacheIndex[url]
    if (cached) return cached

    const cacheFile = await mirrorDirectoryPaths({ cacheLocation, url }),
        data = (await axiosInstance.get(url).catch((e) => { console.log(url, e) })).data
    fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, data)
    cacheIndex[url] = cacheFile

    return cacheFile
}

const urlPlugin = (options = { cacheLocation }) => {
    return {
        async resolveId(importee, importer) {
            //We importing from a URL
            if (/^https?:\/\//.test(importee)) {
                return await writeToDiskCache({ cacheLocation: options.cacheLocation, url: importee })
            }
            //We are importing from a file within the cacheLocation (originally from a URL) and need to continue the cache import chain.
            if (importer && importer.startsWith(options.cacheLocation) && /^..?\//.test(importee)) {
                const importerUrl = Object.keys(cacheIndex).find(key => cacheIndex[key] === importer),
                    importerPath = path.dirname(importerUrl),
                    importeeUrl = path.normalize(`${importerPath}/${importee}`).replace(":\\", "://").replace(/\\/g, "/")
                return await writeToDiskCache({ cacheLocation: options.cacheLocation, url: importeeUrl })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was looking for the same functionality. Imagine with absolute url import, rollup could be used as a static site generator!

Comment: That's right. So long as there are no cross origin issues it makes for a very nice experience developing for the browser. I've updated the snippet which resolves some of the initial issues we had.

Comment: @BlueWater86 You have an hidden issue in your code snippet: urlPlugin `(options = { cacheLocation }) => ` will initialise default value for argument options when it's not defined... with property shorthand, so trying to read a cacheLocation variable that is not defined.  

Perhaps you meant: `(options = { cacheLocation: '' }) =>` or maybe typescript's way `(options: { cacheLocation }) => ` ?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin together with the following config works for me:
https://github.com/mjackson/rollup-plugin-url-resolve

```js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import urlResolve from "rollup-plugin-url-resolve";

export default {
  output: {
    format: "esm",
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({ lib: ["es5", "es6", "dom"], target: "es5" }),
    urlResolve(),
  ],
};
```

You can remove the TypeScript plugin obviously.